# php site limit clicks to a second

Tags: php, click, limit

I have a php site which is a game, and due to the nature of the game, people spam click buttons out of impatience. I think this is causing me grief, requesting data too often from the database etc, so I thought about adding in a click limiter so they can only click once every second, or half a second.

Is there anyway to do this without storing a note in the database of the time of users last click, then comparing it to that if they click too fast? Maybe cookies? javascript? sessions?

Any pointers in the right direction would be useful.

When I say clicks I mean links/buttons that refresh/reload a page etc- basically pagecalls.

UPDATE: Each page requests a lot of data, so Im thinking maybe a session check at the top of the page before it continues is easiest?

Comment: Using cookies and/or JavaScript is easy to bypass.  You better stick with using a database.

Comment: Easy to bypass, but the goal isn't to forcefully prevent users from submitting, but to ease load on the server. Most users won't know how to bypass JS.

Comment: What do you want to happen when they click too many times?  Should something happen a second later, or should nothing happen?

Comment: it just say "You're clicking too fast, chill!"

Answer (score 1):

I would try to create javascript controls with `setTimeout` to limit when the action buttons are clickable.

Failing that, if the problem is refreshing the browser really fast, use something that can detect + reject flood before the requests hit your PHP scripts

If you have control of your apache / server setup you could use something like http://code.google.com/p/autodrop/ - Access flood protection script for Apache access log. Blocks certain ips exceeding defined treshold via iptables. Useful for load balancing API access

Answer (score 0):

The only way that would actually limit traffic to the server is by preventing clicks with Javascript, since this is client side. For the majority of users this would be fine, although some may have it disabled or know how to remove it.

Using sessions would be the more "correct" way, but then you still get some strain on your servers.

Comment: just a simple: session_start(); $_SESSION['click'] = now(); on each page?

Comment: Something like that, and then check the time between clicks to ensure its not too fast.

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is just the database, and not the backend php servers, put it in memcache.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set the onclick for all clickable objects on the page to disable all other clickable objects on the page for a specific time and then re-enable them. If they have nothing to click on, they have no way of spam clicking.

Comment: with (for example) chrome inspector you can remove/edit javascript, so this would not be something to trust

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest method is to make all the server-side scripts run for at least the time-out period. e.g. If you want to enforce a 2 second delay between clicks, then  do

```
<?php


session_start();    

$start = microtime(true);

.... do stuff

$end = microtime(true);

if (($end - $start) < 2) {
   sleep (2 - ($end - $start));
}
```

Having each script keep the session open (assuming you're on the standard file-based session)handler will effectively lock out the user while this script is running, as PHP locks the session file while it's in use, and prevents any parallel hits from starting up while the lock is held.

The time calculations just enforce the time delay, so that even if the user spams the heck out of the refresh button, they'll still only ever get one page every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

same question, different topic, and same answer:

```
session_start();

$now = time();

if ($_SESSION['click'] > ($now-1)) { 
    exit("You're clicking too fast") ; 
}

$_SESSION['click'] = $now;
```